# When using @Secured annotation, getting "AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException:An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Works fine without @secured annotation

My Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class JSONController {

    @Secured({ "ROLE_USER" })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/yagger/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getPersonInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

        User person = new User();
        person.setFirstName(name);

        return person;
    }
}`
```

Spring-Security

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Just for testing... -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/cache_approvals" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" />
    <http pattern="/oauth/uncache_approvals" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" />


    <!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block so we can deal with authorization and error handling 
        separately. This isn't mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
    <!-- http pattern="/yagger/*" auto-config="true" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/yagger/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http-->

    <!-- http pattern="/test/*" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/test/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http-->

    <http xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" create-session="stateless" pattern="/oauth/token">
            <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
            <!-- for PRODUCTION requires-channel="https" -->
            <anonymous enabled="false" />
            <http-basic entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
            <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
                parameters -->
            <custom-filter before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" />
            <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        </http>
    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="yagger" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="yagger/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/oauth/token" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Used for the persistenceof tokens (currently an in memory implementation) -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <!-- Used to create token and and every thing about them except for their persistence that is reposibility of TokenStore (Given here is a           default implementation) -->
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>

    <!-- authorization-server aka AuthorizationServerTokenServices is an interface that defines everything necessary for token management -->
    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" >
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="yagger" token-services-ref="tokenServices" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <!-- ClientsDeailsService: Entry Point to clients database (given is in memory implementation) -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="the_client" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
            authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" resource-ids="yagger"/>

    <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client-with-secret" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
            secret="somesecret" authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write,trust" resource-ids="yagger"/>

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

</beans>
```

myproject-servlet.xml has these related details

```
<beans:alias name="userOauthDetailsService" alias="userDetailsService"/>
    <beans:bean id="userOauthDetailsService" class="com.devyug.yagger.services.impl.UserOauthDetailsService" />
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" secured-annotations="enabled">
        <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>
```

Returns token when 
http://localhost:8080/YaggerWeb/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client-with-secret&client_secret=somesecret&username=abhiljain&password=password

Buth when 
http://localhost:8080/YaggerWeb/yagger/sdfghjjhg?access_token=30d3b413-8691-4a8c-8f17-af0b756f3ce0
Gives 
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
Please let me know if some other details are required

Comment: That URL isn't protected by Spring Security and as such the `SecurityContextHolder` isn't going to be populated. You have no `http` element for anything other then `/oath` starting URLs everything else is basically not protected.

Comment: @M.Deinum .. any corrections ?

Comment: You need to add an `http` element that secures the actual resources, you are currently securing nothing.